# View template files of Helm chart

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm

With `helm inspect [CHART]` I can view the content of `chart.yaml` and `values.yaml` of a chart. Is there a way to also view the template files of a chart? Preferably through a Helm command.

On a sidenote: this seems like a pretty important feature to me. I would always want to know what the chart exactly does before installing it. Or is this not what `helm inspect` was intended for? Might the recommended way be to simply check GitHub for details how the chart works?

Comment: `helm template yourchart`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to check the templates for given chart you can use `helm template [chartname]` command.

The docs describe it as :

> Render chart templates locally and display the output.
>
> Any values that would normally be looked up or retrieved in-cluster will be faked locally. Additionally, none of the server-side testing of chart validity (e.g. whether an API is supported) is done.

Answer (score 17):

`helm install yourchart --dry-run --debug`

This will print to stdout all the rendered templates in the chart (and won't install the chart)

Comment: I’ll mark this one as the answer for now. I’d prefer to see where each variable fits in the template. But it’s pretty damn close to what I want to accomplish.

Answer (score 10):

you can use `helm fetch` if you want to download the whole chart:

> download a chart from a repository and (optionally) unpack it in local directory

(from the [doc](https://github.com/kubernetes/helm/blob/master/docs/helm/helm_fetch.md))

`helm inspect` returns the default `values.yaml` for the chart:

> This command inspects a chart and displays information. It takes a chart reference ('stable/drupal'), a full path to a directory or packaged chart, or a URL.
>
> Inspect prints the contents of the Chart.yaml file and the values.yaml file.

(from the [doc](https://github.com/kubernetes/helm/blob/master/docs/helm/helm_inspect.md))

Comment: I'd prefer not to save anything locally, but it's at least easier than visiting GitHub.